# Большое кол-во потоков

Tags: java

У меня в программе создается огромное кол-во потоков (>10000). Использую ExecutorService. Понятное дело выскакивает исключение OutOfMemory.
Вопрос: Как можно удалить/убрать потоки, которые уже завершились?

Comment: А какой `ExecutorService` используете?

Comment: Как создаете потоки? Пример кода.

Comment: а зачем такое кол-во тредов? может тредпул?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользовавшись функцией service.shutdown() решил проблему

Answer (score 0):

ExecutorService подразумевает инициализацию пула потоков с фиксированным размером пула, например:`ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);`. В данном случае более 10 потоков одновременно стартовать не смогут, они будут поставлены в очередь и будут ждать пока в пуле не освободится место, т.е. один из запущенных потоков не завершит свою работу.

Comment: А откуда уверенность, что используется именно FixedThreadPool?

Comment: Надо использовать `FixedThreadPool`, что бы не запускать одновременно 10000 потоков.

Comment: Потоки в фиксированном пуле не будут завершаться, даже если в пул больше не поступают задачи. Пул, регулирующий время жизни потока - это `newCachedThreadPool`. Ему можно задать время простоя, по истечении которого бездействующий поток будет действительно завершаться. А если задач будет слишком много, то количество потоков будет увеличиваться.

Comment: Если потоки не завершаются самостоятельно, то это уже вообще всё неправильно! "Висящий" поток, как мне кажется, возможен только при "прослушивании" какого-либо порта, но не могу себе представить приложение которому потребовалось слушать более 10000 портов одновременно. `FixedThreadPool` или `CachedThreadPool` не важно, главное в данном случае нужен pool.

Comment: иногда висящие 10000 потоков лучше, чем периодически подыхающие и заново создающиеся 10000 потоков (но это уже выходит за пределы заданного вопроса). И при чем тут порты?

Comment: 10k потоков достаточно сложно создать, а на 32битной системе практически невозможно. Поэтому, выбирать "постоянно высящие" или "постоянно создавать" - бессмысленно.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov мне кажется наша с вами дискуссия потекла не в том направлении. Автор вопроса объявил о своей проблеме с большим количеством потоков, мы с вами посоветовали ему использовать какой-нибудь Pool. По моему, это правильно. Какой именно ему использовать Pool он решит сам, исходя из своих потребностей. Т.к. он не описал подробно свою проблему и не представил исходный код, мы с вами можем только догадываться об этом и бесконечно и безрезультатно спорить. Давайте жить дружно.